# Get content Focus on WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus

so im really not good at this xaml thing and i tried to look everywhere but couldn't find anything usefull for me, hopefully someone will be able to help me here.

So i have a datagrid with TemplateColumns where i have some controls in it such TextBox's and ComboBox's. What im trying to accomplish here is when i tab from one control i would like to focus on the next control in the same row but what is happening now is the column gets focus and only after that when i press tab again the control will be focus, in less words i have to tab twice to jump from one control to another. My datagrid looks like this:

```
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Omschrijving" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox TabIndex="0" Name="txtOms" Text="{Binding txtOmschrijving}" Width="140" Height="24" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one could give a hint or help i kinda digged down on the internetzz and found a solution, hopefully will help someone else in need:

```
    Private Sub dgKasStaatRegels_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles dgKasStaatRegels.Loaded
    Try
        Dim CellFocusedChangedHandler As New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf FocusChangedHandler)
        [AddHandler](DataGridCell.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, CellFocusedChangedHandler)
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteErrorLog("ucKasStaat", "dgKasStaatRegels_Loaded", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub FocusChangedHandler(sender As Object, args As RoutedEventArgs)
    If args.RoutedEvent.RoutingStrategy = RoutingStrategy.Bubble Then
        Dim DataGridCellObj As FrameworkElement = TryCast(args.OriginalSource, FrameworkElement)
        If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab) Then
            If DataGridCellObj IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim txtb As TextBox = TryCast(DataGridCellObj, TextBox)
                If txtb IsNot Nothing Then txtb.Focus()

                Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(DataGridCellObj, ComboBox)
                If cb IsNot Nothing Then
                    cb.Focus()
                    cb.IsDropDownOpen = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Public Shared Function FindParent(Of T As DependencyObject)(dependencyObject As DependencyObject) As T
    Dim parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject)

    If parent Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim parentT = TryCast(parent, T)
    Return If(parentT, FindParent(Of T)(parent))
End Function
```

Quick explanation: on the datagrid load add a CellFocusedChangedHandler handler and in that sub just track if the object inside that row is a Textbox(in my case) and set its focus!

It worked for me!